# How to share a PHP project?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Me and two friends want to build something in common in PHP, probably all of us are going to use eclipse for that, but some use Ubuntu and some use Windows.

Is there any convince and good why to share the code and develop together freely? Thanks!

And we don't want our project to be open source in this case :(

Comment: @ZoZo123: github can host private source, you just have to pay a small fee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your platform, i would recommend following:

**SVN Provider**:

[SpringLoops](http://www.springloops.com/v2?r=3483367175402) (Ref. Link)
I've been with them for 2.5 years now, blazing fast support. It has some rock-solid features like **auto remote deployment** so if you [commit](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html) it instantly deploys to the remote server so you have the actual version running on the FTP too.

As far as i can tell you, KEEP AWAY from **BeanStalk** as provider, they are copying SpringLoops and have roughly the same features but theirs work very very slow. There are waiting times for remote deploy of 120 seconds in average.

**Mac OS X**:

I've extensively used Versionsapp from Sofa but in the last 2 years it did not receive any (major) update at all so i purchased [CornerStone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php) and it's working very very good. You can keep track of anything that happens to the repository.

**Windows**:
If you are using windows, i would work with [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) which works with the windows Shell so you give the commands via the shell menu. It's easy to use and is developed since a very long time.

If you have any questions write a comment and I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use a Subversion (SVN) or Git repository. These are tools that enable several developers to work on the same project at the same time, managing conflicts and versions of the code.

For free solutions, please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378120/is-there-a-free-private-git-repository

How to install Subversive, a free Subversion client for eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php

Comment: Go with Git rather than subversion, it's all the rage these days!

Answer (score 1):

I think bitbucket is a great solution for sharing a small project with your friends and make it privately for free.

https://bitbucket.org/